# Ubuntu 20.04 takes 30 seconds to suspend

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, xubuntu, suspend, delay

I updated from Xubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 during the pre-release on a Dell XPS 13 (2013). When clicking suspend the WIFI is turned of immediately, then nothing happens for exactly 30 seconds, then it suspends.

It used to take only a second or so. It has been like this for a couple of months I think, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any logs, or any error message?

Comment: Good point, I will check the system logs.